# Reuse a site recaptcha key (bypass it) for a desktop app (bot)

Tags: recaptcha

I'm trying to write a bot for discovering some specific Ads in an Advertisement website.
When I trying to catch info from an Ad, I can see in the inspector that website send a POST request to google which is as follows:

`https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/reload?k=6LegZHIU*******************************kg`

The result of this request is something like this:

`)]}'
["rresp","03AOLTBLRE2Nrcq5Vf5weIaxGU1OnjEfROFc**********************FqgvBHdDtMNwk1Q",null,120,null,null,null,["bgdata",...........`

I need a new of the key which is starts with "03AOL", So, When I do the same request from *Postman*, I take nothing (null response) like as:

`)]}'
["rresp",null,null,null,null,null,1]`.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: (If what you wanted was easily possible, then these CAPTCHAs would be rather useless in the first place …)

Comment: I think there must be a solution, because I just need to simulate one click in client side not much. The last way is click simulation in website, but I want to know a simpler solution.

Comment: I can regenerate it by Chrome inspector: After inspecting the base page, I can right click on the request and select Replay XHR. It generates a new key!